# How to add button to html table cell?

Tags: html

I had to create an HTML table to retrieve data from the database. In each row, I need to add a button called status. How do I do that?
This is my table code

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Reference No</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Assigned Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Status
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<body>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
    <td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
```

this is an image of the sample table
[image]
except for these texts, I need to add that button called status to change status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this once..

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
      <th scope="col">Reference No</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Assigned Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Status
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<body>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td><button>status</button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>@fat</td> 
    <td><button>status</button></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
    <td>@twitter</td> 
    <td><button>status</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your are printing from database than you can write this

```
 <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Reference No</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Assigned Date</th>
          <th scope="col">Status
          </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $refid ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $description ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $assigneddate ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $status ?><button>Status</button></td>
     </tr>
```